# google script producing unexpected error on reading spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

```
var staffSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AvHCNzkk36UPdENnQndpZ3VoUmVUUjJmOEZjVTBQNXc');
var staff_active_sheet = staffSheet.getSheetByName("Staff");
var staffs = staff_active_sheet.getRangeByName("A1:C" + staff_active_sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
```

Comment: It Just gives an alert saying Error Encountered: unexpected error occurred. I tried disabling parts of the code and it came down to the line that says staff_active_sheet.getRangeByName(  . Not sure if it might be a conflict, because in the function calling this, I am writing to another spreadsheet.

Comment: please add the information in your comment to the question, it makes more sense and makes it more useful to others :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `getRangeByName` on a [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sheet), which doesn't exist.  You probably want to be calling `getRange`.

Comment: to be more accurate, `getRangeByName()` belongs to the spreadsheet method, see doc [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet#getRangeByName)